# Is it possible to group cups print jobs so they will not be interrupted by other users print jobs?

Tags: linux, network-printer, cups

I am working on printing very large images on a custom type printer, in linux, using cups.

Because of memory limitations, the images are broken in chunks. Each chunk is sent to printer using cupsPrintFile() function - that sets, among othe options, feed and cut to be done only on the last image. The intent is to have all the smaller images sent to create the original large image.

My question is, how to group the print jobs to avoid other users printing to the same printer to send jobs in-between the chunks of the same image ?

(I am aware that printer protocols are doing the exact opposite, optimizing resources they allow different jobs to be processed out of sequence... But in this case, that would be very bad).

(An alternative is to use the cupsPrintFiles that sends all required files as a single job - the problem is hat they all have the same print options, and I cannot figure out how I could set a different page size for the last file, which will be smaller).

If there are any cups commands that allow print jobs to be grouped would be great, because I can try to find the equivalent c++ commands or just try to run the terminal commands from a shell inside the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [2dir](https://community.kde.org/Printing/Developer_Tools#.272dir.27_CUPS_backend_script_.28Bash_code.29) script to create a virtual printer, then combined the resulting print jobs.